# Statically-typed Dynamic Lookup for Record

Tags: f#

I'm trying to `statically type` a `record field` and then return that `field` (unique items only to be exact).

So it would look something like this:

```
type Item = {Id:int; Name:string}
  with
    member this.field fieldName =
      let info = getInfo fieldName
      this 
      |> Seq.map (fun record -> FSharpValue.GetRecordField info)
      |> Seq.distinct |> Seq.sort |> Array.ofSeq

let item = {Id = 1; Name = "First"}
let ids = item.field Item.Id
```

I found [this old write up by Tomas Petricek](http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-dynamic-lookup.aspx/) on the subject but I would think there would be a better way with `F# 3.0` that would also extend to `VB`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really need to use reflection or dynamic lookup in this case. It works quite nicely if you represent the "lookup" using a function that returns the field of the record. If you use `System.Func` rather than F# function type, then it will be nicely usable from all .NET languages:

```
type Item = 
  {Id:int; Name:string}

type ItemList =
  { Items : Item list }
  member this.Field(fn:System.Func<Item, 'T>) =
    this.Items
    |> Seq.map fn.Invoke
    |> Seq.distinct |> Seq.sort |> Array.ofSeq

let items = 
  { Items = [ {Id = 1; Name = "First"}
              {Id = 2; Name = "First"}
              {Id = 3; Name = "Second"} ] }

let names = items.Field(fun r -> r.Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
type Item = {Id:int; Name:string}
  with
    member x.field fieldName =
        let types = FSharpType.GetRecordFields(x.GetType()) |> Array.map (fun p -> p.Name)
        let values = FSharpValue.GetRecordFields(x)
        Array.zip types values
        |> Array.tryFind (fst >> (=) fieldName)
        |> Option.map (snd >> unbox)

let item = {Id = 1; Name = "First"}
let ids: int option = item.field "Id"
```